# android phonegap installation on command prompt — Error: EPERM, errno: 50

Tags: android, git, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Am new to this PhoneGap application development when i tried to install phonegap with install (http://phonegap.com/install/) guide from command prompt this says me more error
like

```
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', pa
th: 'C:\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js " "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log' npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Where as i install Git as well but why this error comes ? and is there any other way to install and work on phonegap ?

Comment: i got that error too...its a repeated question.
try- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290899/git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps :

- Download and install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Following installation, you should be able to invoke node and npm on your command line.
- Download and install a [git client](http://git-scm.com/), if you don't already have one. Following installation, you should be able to invoke git on your command line.
- Install the cordova module using npm utility of Node.js. The cordova module will automatically be downloaded by the npm utility.

On OS X and Linux: *`$ sudo npm install -g cordova`*

On Windows: *`C:\>npm install -g cordova`*

Source : [PhoneGap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: Hi Thank you, Can you help (Guide) me how to configure this into eclipse to create and run projects...

Comment: Yes Sure..What issue are you facing?

Comment: am not able to create new project with phoneGap

Comment: Just follow the link that I mentioned in the answer and create a project through CLI and import the project in Eclipse.

Comment: D:\phonegap_source>$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
'$cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\phonegap_source>

Comment: Are you using Mac or Linux to create your application?

Comment: If you are using Windows then the command would be as "D:\phonegap_source>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld". No need to add "$" sign in windows.