# phonegap run android - create Command failed with exit code 8 - linux

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I did some googleing but find nothing approriate.
Any help appreciated. Try it with an naked vm to be sure 
having no nodejs install or dependency issue.

Christian

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy 
sudo npm install -g phonegap 
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo apt-get install ant

chris@mint16 ~/project/dev $ phonegap create my-app
[phonegap] create called with the options /home/chris/project/dev/my-app       com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
[phonegap] Customizing default config.xml file
[phonegap] created project at /home/chris/project/dev/my-app
chris@mint16 ~/project/dev $ cd my-app/
chris@mint16 ~/project/dev/my-app $ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

/home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at /home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
at _rejected  (/home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when    (/home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
{ [Error: /home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with   exit code 8] code: 8 }
[error] /home/chris/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with  exit code 8
```

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281663/1785412

Comment: Hmm cordova is installed. Now I did this hello world example and always this exception from cordova. But with  **cordova platform add android** I got again this q.js:126 exception?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've just faced the same issue, the problem was that path to sdk tools was not properly setup:

So try the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools
```

Comment: Thanks much! You saved my days :) In my case I had to add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` to make my jenkins job runnable on macOS mojave
.

Answer (score 1):

I also hit the same issue, but just adding the various android sdk tools directories to the path as DKMudrechenko suggested above did not help.  It turned out that I had not installed ant properly.  I had downloaded it from apache.org and just added the ant 'bin' folder to my path, but apparently that wasn't good enough.  However, after removing that entry from my path statement and adding ant via brew, I was then able to build the android cordova project successfully using the 'cordova build android' command.

Answer (score 1):

i have been facing this issue on and off only to realise that the build fails for other errors in the code/configuration. 
the process you have taken does skip one part where the android platform is added

```
corodova platforms add android
```

in the steps given above, you have created a project, traversed into the project directory and then ran the build, to which the phone gap checked the installed sdks by checking ANDROID_HOME and tried to set up the project for android.

you might want to run it in a correct order:

1. create project
2. move to the project directory
3. add platform
4. build / run.

i hope this helps