# While running command npm install -g cordova in cli getting error in windows

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

> c:>npm install -g cordova

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/-/xcode-0.6.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/-/xcode-0.6.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/-/xcode-0.6.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz

npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1365:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:977:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:323:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:585:24)
npm ERR!     at flow (_stream_readable.js:594:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:626:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd c:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'c:\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'c:\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', pa
th: 'c:\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd c:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path c:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'c:\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**I tried below command in cli**

> c:>npm config set strict-ssl false

and then executed command

> c:>npm install -g cordova

It gives following result

```
C:\Users\e01005\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\e01005\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4 C:\Users\e01005\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── q@0.9.7
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
└── cordova-lib@0.21.3 (osenv@0.0.3, bplist-parser@0.0.5, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.
0.11, shelljs@0.1.4, plist-with-patches@0.5.1, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.3.0, elemen
ttree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.6, glob@3.2.9, npmconf@0.1.16, tar@0.1.19, request@2.22.0
, npm@1.3.4)
```

and  when  I run command **cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**

it says

> 'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I not getting whats the issue why it **not allow me to create the projects** some time it create project but not allow to add platform.

**Environment variable PATH value is**

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281663/1785412

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

npm fetched and installed cordova successfully

Answer (score 0):

Install `git` before installing Cordova. In the background, it downloads from Git.