# npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git

Tags: android, node.js, git, react-native

I followed the [React native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#content) official docs step by step, but as soon as I executed the command `react-native init MedFirstRN` from windows cmd, I received the following error:

```
D:\projects>react-native init MedFirstRN
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in D:\projects\MedFirstRN
Installing react-native package from npm...

npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\android\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:73:28)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\android\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:76:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\android\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:84:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git://github.com/facebook/react.git#b4e74e38e43ac53af8acd62c78c9213be0194245 resetting remote C:\Users\Moughaoui\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-r
emotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e38e43ac53af8acd62c78c9213be0194245-c92d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'EN
OGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Moughaoui\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Moughaoui\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e38e43ac53af8acd62c78c9213be0194245-c92d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Moughaoui\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Moughaoui\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e38e43ac53af8acd62c78c9213be0194245-c92d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\android\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\android\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\projects\MedFirstRN\npm-debug.log

`npm install --save react-native` failed

D:\projects>
```

Can you help please?

When I execute this command from Git Shell it works.

Comment: Crazy... Looks like you're on windows, so I'm probably not going to be much help... but maybe try installing git again for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to install git with `Run Git from Windows Command Prompt` option selected. This option will add the git executable to your `PATH` which seems to be missing and causing this error.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614660/157575 for more details.