# 'Error: not found: git' code: 'ENOGIT' while installing bower

Tags: installation, bower-install

I'm using windows 10 with git and node installed. Running :

```
npm install -g bower
```

resulsts in

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  sheerun/fs-write-stream-atomic#v1.0.4-fix resetting remote C:\Users\Muhammet Akkus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-sheerun-fs-write-stream-atomic-git-v1-0-4-fix-7baaaaefc7e8a6f2fd1f4fdbc8e4b6e7 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Muhammet Akkus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/sheerun/fs-write-stream-atomic.git C:\Users\Muhammet Akkus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-sheerun-fs-write-stream-atomic-git-v1-0-4-fix-7baaaaefc7e8a6f2fd1f4fdbc8e4b6e7: undefined
```

....

Answer (score 4):

You should try to run this command as root. On Windows, start your CommandLine as administrator and under Mac or Linux use

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: using sudo with node modules is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Installing git and running npm install from git-bash worked for me. Make sure you are in the correct directory.

Refer more here for solution
[git is not installed or not in the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290899/git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path)