# Error not found Git - trying Aurelia.js

Tags: git, npm, aurelia

I'm currently wanting to try out `Aurelia.js`.
I'm not familiar with `node.js` and its modules but `Aurelia` has a sort of starter page here:

**[Setting up the Project Structure and Build](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/a-production-setup**)**

So I followed the steps, installed `node`, then `gulp`, then `jspm`.

Now after these, you download a skeleton containing a `package.json` which I understand is what's going to be installed when I run **"npm install"**. However, I can't seem to get this to work.

> It says I don't have Git.

So I downloaded Git, installed it, then I check my path environment variables and it has this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

But still, `npm` won't install. The first line immediately says

> "addRemoteGit Error: not found: git".

Also, at the bottom, there is a message

> "Please check if you have Git installed and in your PATH."

Comment: Possible answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290899/git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path

Comment: Try open command prompt in administrator mode

Comment: Checkout if you have installed git correctly by typing git in your command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your machine does not have the `git` executable in your path.

#### How to verify if git installed correctly?

- Open your `cmd` and type git.
  or
- Open git bash and type git there.

#### What to do if git is not installed?

Re-install git and choose this option:

[image]

#### What to do if git is installed?

Open your `git bash` and inside your project folder run `npm install`

If its working you shall see something like this:

[image]