# Npm not installing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

[image]i'm new to react native. I'm working on Weather App. I'm trying to run the app .But the npm is not installing. I'm getting this error.
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

The url of the code is https://github.com/nazmulidris/react-native-weather

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Can you post the Screenshot of the error?

Comment: plzz see the above image i have added the screenshot of the error

Comment: use this'  npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: same error i'm getting

Comment: okay lets start from base then,
open new CMD and type npm -v,tell me what it shows

Comment: it's 6.5.0   ......

Comment: could you let us know your environment path variables? Maybe an issue with the path value.

Comment: sure what you want I'll tell you

Comment: from start menu, search for system environment variables -> edit -> you will see a variable named 'PATH' -> edit it -> paste the complete value here.

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Comment: this is the path

Comment: Your npm seems fine, try installing git , npm install -g git-install

Comment: A word of caution, cmd needs to be restarted after you try any of the above suggestions. I would suggest use cmd (run as admin) instead of IDE terminal. Just to make sure it's not a problem with the IDE

Also, using Gitbash may help you temporarily.

Comment: now i'm get only loading after running  npm install -g git-install, then i try to run npm install its loading nothing is happening from that time

Comment: thanks , it is npm is installed

Comment: i'm getting this problem now E:\React Project\react-native-weather-bc5923578527612007198fc5024a9dca723c86b9\node_modules (20ms)
error: unknown option `--bundle'

Comment: when i'm running this react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Comment: Do you have idea why this error is coming

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `git` client is not installed on your system. See the installation instruction [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git). I think after doing that, the `npm` problem will be resolved.

Comment: I installed the git also

Comment: can you plzz see if this project run on your system

Comment: ya, i will try and tell you the result.

Comment: `npm install` command completed with no errors. I'm on Ubuntu with npm version `6.4.1` and git `2.17.1`.  
Could you please run the `git --version` command and report the result you get?

Comment: The error message in the screenshot you posted obviously says:
`No git binary found in the PATH. Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH`.   
Error messages is your friend.

Comment: git version 2.20.1. windows.1

Comment: this is what i get

Comment: So the problem is somewhere between git and windows, in linux no issue I see. So try to search the exact error message: `no git binary found in $path`.
Take a look at this links:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614660/3235344
https://github.com/orktes/atom-react/issues/106#issuecomment-197328359

Comment: i have installed the npm install

Comment: But now i'm getting the error  E:\React Project\react-native-weather-bc5923578527612007198fc5024a9dca723c86b9\node_modules (20ms) error: unknown option `--bundle'

Comment: when i'm running this lib in terminal react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Comment: This is a separate question, if the initial problem which is explained in the question is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted or you yourself post an answer to help other people who encounter this issue. And you can post the new issue in a new question.